# What will go wrong if a recursive record type has a negative eta rule?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type

In the context of Agda like dependent type theory:

This short paper https://jesper.sikanda.be/files/vectors-are-records-too.pdf says some inductive type can be seen as records, for example `Vector` of fixed-length list can be seen as inductively-defined family of **non-recursive** types.

But they argue that for example natural number type should not have a eta rule because it is a recursive type (the original paper says `N = Unit \/ N` is non-terminating.)

So what will go wrong if we have this type:

```
data out where
  cons : out => out

in : out => out
in (cons a) = a
```

and give it a negative eta-rule:

`(a: out)`  then  `a = cons (in a)` judgementally

Can it proof `False`? Or just this is a bad idea....?

---

edit: It seems Agda has eta-rule for recursive records? but not for the one previously defined, see this issue https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/402 . but the previously defined one is ruled out I think by implementation issues, not theoretical one?

Comment: Note that `out` is an empty type in Agda.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Yes this is explained in the issue. So if Agda permits this eta rule, where can I found a semantical justification? or is it trivial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a recursive record type with eta-equality wouldn't destroy consistency of the theory, but it would destroy decidability of typechecking.

For example, let's define your `out` type as a record type in Agda:

```
record Out : Set where
  inductive
  constructor cons
  field
    in : Out
```

Agda doesn't use eta-equality for this type. Suppose it did, then Agda's typechecker would loop whenever it tries to solve an equation of the form `x = y : Out` (where `x` and `y` are two variables or neutral terms): `x = y` iff `in x = in y` iff `in (in x) = in (in y)` iff `in (in (in x)) = in (in (in y))` ...

Comment: Is this just true for Agda or generally all implementations? If we don't have meta variable and unification, can we don't eta-expand when both side are generic value, and just return `x != y`?

Comment: This argument only shows that a certain typechecking strategy isn’t termination, but it doesn’t seem to prove that typechecking is undecidable, or do I miss something?
@molikto even without type inference, type checking needs to decide if terms are judgmentally/definitionally equal.

Comment: This is true in general, see [this paper](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csetzer/articles/CMCS2018/bergerSetzerProceedingsCMCS18.pdf) by Berger and Setzer.

Comment: @HenningBasold I don't think this paper is related. it deals with coinductive types without eta rules, the recursive record type I mentioned is a special case of inductive type

Comment: I now understand that the above is even true without meta variables. The "equations" is just type directed conversion checking algorithm. But still, one choice is turn off eta for non-guarded recursive record. Another one is simply say all items of a non-guarded recursive record is equal. They are empty anyway. Not sure if this is sound. (practically this doesn't matter, because these types has not much use?)